# Add additional information to db query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following working piece of code.

```
DB::table('plates')
        ->join('projects', 'plates.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('equipment_status_codes', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment_status_codes.id')
        ->select('projects.name AS Project', 'equipment_status_codes.name AS StatusCode', DB::raw('count(plates.id) as no_of_plates'))
        ->groupBy('plates.project_id', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id')
        ->get();
```

This works just fine. It returns the following.

```
[
  {
    "Project": "Mose Kuvalis",
    "StatusCode": "Dr. Ava Mraz",
    "no_of_plates": 5
  }
]
```

Although I still have like 10 plates left over which **doesn't** have any project(s) or statuscode(s) attached to it (so basically null as value). Can I have this in the same query (same json)?? and return something like this (doesn't have to be the same though)

```
[
  {
    "Project": "Mose Kuvalis",
    "StatusCode": "Dr. Ava Mraz",
    "no_of_plates": 5
  },
  {
    "Project": NULL,
    "StatusCode": NULL,
    "no_of_plates": 10 // or some other number
  },
]
```

Thanks for your time!

Based on suggestion I have updated the query but still returning the same results.

```
      return  DB::table('plates')
        ->join('projects', 'plates.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('equipment_status_codes', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment_status_codes.id')
        ->select( DB::raw('IFNULL(projects.name, NULL) as Project'), DB::raw('IFNULL(equipment_status_codes.name, NULL) as StatusCode'), DB::raw('count(plates.id) as no_of_plates'))
        ->groupBy('plates.project_id', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `DB::raw()` inside select and Should use IFNULL for each select field.

IFNULL example::

```
IFNULL(projects.name, NULL) AS Project
```

Comment: Maybe is me can't get this right. I have update the post, would you have a look.  Thanks